# How to autogenerate UML diagram for java in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, uml, plantuml

I created a medium-sized project in java using IntelliJ, and for my presentation, I need to have a UML diagram of the project structure. Since the project is not particularly small, I wanted to find a plugin that would draw the diagram for me. I've tried installing PlantUML but the only option it provides is writing the whole diagram yourself.
Any ideas or suggestions? Thank you in advance for any helpful input.

Comment: Right click on the class -> Diagrams -> "Show Diagram" / "Show local changes as UML"

Comment: Thats good thanks! But how can i view more than one class in the same diagram? I only managed to view one class at a time

Comment: Try right clicking on the project and repeat the above steps

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked great! I'd mark it as the correct answer but can't since it's a comment

Comment: Do you want me to add this as an Answer?

Comment: @SivaRahul Just do that. Even if it's a trivial one, if that's the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the project -> Diagrams -> Show Diagram... -> Java classes Diagram